# How to add options menu (either 3 dots and/or action icons) to a tabbed activity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I started my project with the template "Tabbed Activity" and am now trying to add an options menu. I have done this before with a blank activity and it worked fine. As far as I can tell I have done all the same steps, even as outlined by the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#options-menu

When I run the app, nothing shows up. I would expect to see the 3 dots icon. I also tried adding icons to see if they would show up as actions. No luck. Here's what I've got in my MainActivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu_layout, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.settingsMenuItem:
                ShowSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void ShowSettings() {
        // TODO show settings
    }
}
```

And this is the options menu xml file which is "options_menu_layout.xml" located in the res/menu directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settingsMenuItem"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_settings_black_48"
        android:title="@string/menu_option_settings"/>
</menu>
```

This seems to work on a blank activity, but not in this tabbed activity. Is there something I'm missing that is required to make these compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when using the template "Tabbed Activity" the manifest file uses a "NoActionBar" version of the theme.
I deleted the last part of this line:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.ExampleApp.NoActionBar">
```

So it is this instead:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.ExampleApp">
```

Answer (score 0):

show the xml, style and manifest files.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [onCreateOptionsMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?authuser=1#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)),

> "You must return true for the panel to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown."

In your code sample, you have `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`.

Is there a reason for calling the parent's class method as well?  (The android developer [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#java) code sample also does a `return true;`)

So I would first try to change onCreateOptionsMenu() to `return true;` to see if the options menu shows up and as a next step investigate the need to call the parent class' super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu).